# how sliding window functions work in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, analytics

I've a doubt regarding sliding window function in spark. I'll be receiving json events from stream, and I would like to see top value out of all messages I've received in last 1 hour.

So If I apply this logic using `tumbling or sliding window function`, then does it means, I'll get the output after every one hour ?

2. Does spark stores all events for the time frame I've mentioned in window function to get largest/top value ?

Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Spark supports three types of time windows: tumbling (fixed), sliding and session.

0. `tumbling window` is different from `sliding window`

[image: types of time windows]

1. `tumbling window` is fixed-size.If you have used `tumbling window`, you can get the output every one hour with configuration. Yet if you have used `sliding window`, you can get topN of all messages you've received in last 1 hour(previous 60 minutes)
2. Spark we use the `state` store provider to handle the stateful operations.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#types-of-time-windows

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#state-store